# Two foreign keys of the same table. How do I write this SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, mysql

### Users Table

```
user_id    username    thumb_id    fullimage_id
1          jprescott   14          15
2          lpausch     18          19
```

### Images Table

```
image_id    path
14          jprescott/small.jpg
15          jprescott/big.jpg
16          msamuels/small.jpg
17          msamuels/big.jpg
18          lpausch/small.jpg
19          lpausch/big.jpg
```

Now, how do I write a SELECT statement to retrieve a user with the thumb and fullimage paths? The issue is that of having two foreign keys of the same table.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You do two joins:

```
SELECT u.username, i1.path AS thumb, i2.path AS full
  FROM users AS u
    JOIN images AS i1 ON u.thumb_id = i1.image_id
    JOIN images AS i2 ON u.fullimage_id = i2.image_id
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
select u.username, i1.path, i2.path from users u, images i1, images i2 
  where u.user_id = ? and u.thumb_id = i1.image_id and u.fullimage_id = i2.image_id
```