# Two foreign keys of the same table and multiple JOIN with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, join, foreign-keys

I have MySql database with 3 tables:

**language**

lang_id       lang

**word**

word_id      *lang_id*       word

**translation**

trans_id      *word_id1*    *word_id2*

And I want to get all translations between two languages I choose. Following command *(with a wrong syntax)* is based on:

[Two foreign keys of the same table. How do I write this SELECT statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655761/two-foreign-keys-of-the-same-table-how-do-i-write-this-select-statement)

[MySQL multiple Inner Join with Where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435545/mysql-multiple-inner-join-with-where-clause)

In the command I'm trying to get translations between languages *1* and *2*.

```
SELECT w1.word, lang1.lang AS w2.word, lang2.lang AS FULL
    FROM translation AS trans
    (JOIN (word AS w1 JOIN language AS lang1 ON lang1.id_lang=w1.lang_id)
       ON trans.word_id1=w1.id_word WHERE (w1.lang_id=1 OR w1.lang_id=2))
    (JOIN (word AS w2 JOIN language AS lang2 ON lang2.id_lang=w2.lang_id)
       ON trans.word_id2=w2.id_word WHERE (w2.lang_id=1 OR w2.lang_id=2))
```

**SOLUTION**
Thanks to @ahmed-gdoma I came up with this command:

```
SELECT w1.word AS w1, l1.lang AS L1,w2.word AS w2, l2.lang AS L2 FROM translation AS t 
JOIN word AS w1 on w1.id_word=t.word_id1 
JOIN word AS w2 on w2.id_word=t.word_id2
JOIN language AS L1 on w1.lang_id=L1.id_lang
JOIN language AS L2 on w2.lang_id=L2.id_lang
WHERE (l2.id_lang=1 OR l2.id_lang=2) 
AND (l1.id_lang=2 OR l1.id_lang=1)
```

It returns word *(w1)*, its language *(L1)*, translation of the word *(w2)* and language of the translation *(L2*)

Comment: Duplicate of [How to get matching data from another SQL table for two different columns: Inner Join and/or Union?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27682228/3404097)

Comment: You give two unclear descriptions, "all translations between two specific languages" and "get translations between languages 1 and 2" and you give a query that doesn't do that. How are we supposed to know what you want? Give example DDL, input parameters & tables and desired output and use the English language to explain what you want in a way that does not rely on the example. Please read & act on [mcve]. PS [PKs, FKs & other constraints are not needed to query.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23842061/3404097)

Comment: Hi. What does "not working" mean? That query doesn't even parse. Read the syntax for SELECT statements in the manual or even any intro. Your innermost parentheses are unnecessary & your others are grouping illegally. A subquery (ie a select where a table name can go) requires parentheses and an alias. But you don't *need* subqueries because you can do a series of joins. Build your query from parts that you get to work separately.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT w1.word AS L1,w2.word as L2 FROM translation AS t 
JOIN word AS w1 on w1.word_id=t.word_id1 
JOIN word AS w2 on w2.word_id=t.word_id2
```

Comment: Thank you, even this is not what I was asking for, it led to the right command. Your command returns only words, I wanted words + languages. Here is what I came up with:
'SELECT w1.word AS w1, l1.lang AS L1,w2.word AS W2, l2.lang AS L2 FROM translation AS t 
JOIN word AS w1 on w1.id_word=t.word_id1 
JOIN word AS w2 on w2.id_word=t.word_id2
JOIN language AS L1 on w1.lang_id=L1.id_lang
JOIN language AS L2 on w2.lang_id=L2.id_lang'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `FULL` is a **[reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)** in MySQL, and as such, you need to pick a different name for your `AS`.

In the following, I replace this with `COMBINED`:

```
SELECT w1.word, lang1.lang AS w2.word, lang2.lang AS COMBINED
FROM translation AS trans
(JOIN (word AS w1 JOIN language AS lang1 ON lang1.id_lang=w1.lang_id)
   ON trans.word_id1=w1.id_word WHERE (w1.lang_id=1 OR w1.lang_id=2))
(JOIN (word AS w2 JOIN language AS lang2 ON lang2.id_lang=w2.lang_id)
   ON trans.word_id2=w2.id_word WHERE (w2.lang_id=1 OR w2.lang_id=2)
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I got rid of 'AS'es and replaced 'FULL' with 'COMBINED' as you recommended - sadly still doesn't work.

Comment: @ObsidianAge AS is optional both in FROM & SELECT in standard SQL. Also MySQL, tagged here.